# How to achieve the affix navbar bootstrap effect in bulma?

Tags: javascript, css, flexbox, bulma

Idea is when you scroll down the navbar to have some transition and then to stick it to the top. I've done this with bootstrap & jquery but now we are using bulma and plain js.

Any help is appreciated.Thanks.

Comment: Questions seeking help ("**why isn't, or how to make, this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a _specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary_ to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

You need some JavaScript to achieve that, and Bulma is CSS only. Try something like [headroom.js](http://wicky.nillia.ms/headroom.js/)